# Make a button have different normal/hover appearances depending on state

Tags: c#, button, uwp, visualstatemanager

I'm working on making a simple Tic Tac Toe game in C# using UWP.

I'd like to add some effects, so that when the mouse hovers over a cell, it shows a ghost of the symbol.  But if a symbol has already been placed there, it should fade the symbol slightly.

**What would be a good way of achieving this?**

> Example of the desired effects:
>   [image] 
>   Top centre is symbol placed, mouse not over.
>   Centre is symbol placed, mouse over.
>   Centre right is symbol not placed, mouse over.
>   Other cells are symbol not placed, mouse not over.

Currently, I have a ControlTemplate defined as such:

```cs
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="NormalSolid" >
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PlayerIcon">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.75"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSolid">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PlayerIcon">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PlayerIcon">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.25"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PlayerIcon">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.25"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Then, it is changed like so:

```
private void GameButton_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GameButton button = sender as GameButton;
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(button, "Normal" + (!this.ShapePlaced ? "" : "Solid"), true);

}

private void GameButton_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GameButton button = sender as GameButton;
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(button, "PointerOver" + (!this.ShapePlaced ? "" : "Solid"), true);
}
```

(Where GameButton is a simple subclass of Button, and PlayerIcon is a shape representing the shape drawn)

But this leads to problems with click + dragging around the buttons, as well being unreliable. Would it be possible to place the 2 sets of states (shape placed vs not placed) in different VisualStateGroups, and switch the 'active' group depending on it's current state?

Essentially, I need 2 Normal states, 2 PointerOver states, and a way to switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the default Button Style to your liking. It already defines all the states and transitions so you don't need to use the events in code behind.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
<Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The easiest way to obtain this style (and the default style for any control) in Visual Studio 2015 you use the 'Document Outline' tool window. Select the control in the tree view of the window, right click and select Edit Template -> Edit a copy. This will expose the default style of the control and you can modify it and apply it back to the control.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. When looking on the web, i did see that you could do that. However, how would you use that in my case, because I essentially need 2 different "Normal" and "PointerOver" states which can be switched, depending on if the shape is placed or not. Thanks.